# Ruby on Rails - ActiveSupport: Array Extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

In the extensions to the array class (rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb) the following function is defined:

```
# Returns the beginning of the array up to +position+.
def to(position)
  if position >= 0
    take position + 1
  else
    self[0..position]
  end
end
```

Why is it defined like this? Why can't we just do:

```
def to(position)
  self[0..position]
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ed03d4eaa89a7b4ab09e7f5da76b522d04650daf

Answer (score 3):

According to the [commit message of the change in the Rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ed03d4eaa89a7b4ab09e7f5da76b522d04650daf), it looks like they were trying to "Avoid creating range objects".

When I do `arr[0..3]`, the `0..3` part becomes a `Range` object, which then gets used to calculate the subarray.  I'm guessing they were trying to save memory by avoiding this.

Answer (score 1):

It's about efficiency. Since most use case (positive parameter) will fall into the `if` branch and the `Array#take` method easily gives the return, see implementation:

```
               static VALUE
rb_ary_take(VALUE obj, VALUE n)
{
    long len = NUM2LONG(n);
    if (len < 0) {
        # does not take negative parameter
        rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "attempt to take negative size");
    }
    return rb_ary_subseq(obj, 0, len);
}
```

For the `else` branch, we have to create a rang object since `Array#take` does not take a negative parameter (see above c implementation) and hence a little more memory is used.